# How to Simplify Quotient of Complex Exponentials

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, trigonometry

I wonder how to implement certain simplifications that one can "see" but Mathematica's Simplify or similar functions aren't finding...

The particular MWE I have here is:

```
2 Exp[I x] / (1 + Exp[2 I x])
```

which should simplify to

```
Sec[x]
```

I'm happy to guide the simplification process by hand if there is no other way to automate, i.e. tell Mathematica "multiply numerator and denominator by Exp[- I x]", but I don't even know how to do that.

Comment: Just answered my own question: FullSimplify did the trick.

Comment: In addition to `expr//FullSimplify`, you could use either `expr//ExpToTrig//Simplify` or `expr//ComplexExpand//Simplify`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `FullSimplify` can do the job in one step in many cases, you could be interested in other way around.

First, apply `ExpToTrig`:

```
ExpToTrig[(2 E^(I x))/(1 + E^(2 I x))]

(* (2 (Cos[x] + I Sin[x]))/(1 + Cos[2 x] + I Sin[2 x]) *)
```

then, `ComplexExpand` with `TargetFunctions->{Re, Im}` to separate real and imaginary parts:

```
(2 (Cos[x] + I Sin[x]))/(1 + Cos[2 x] + I Sin[2 x]) // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] &
```

$\frac{2 \cos (2 x) \cos (x)}{\sin ^2(2 x)+(\cos (2 x)+1)^2}+\frac{2 \cos (x)}{\sin ^2(2 x)+(\cos (2 x)+1)^2}+\frac{2 \sin (x) \sin (2 x)}{\sin ^2(2 x)+(\cos (2 x)+1)^2}+i \left(\frac{2 \sin (x) \cos (2 x)}{\sin ^2(2 x)+(\cos (2 x)+1)^2}+\frac{2 \sin (x)}{\sin ^2(2 x)+(\cos (2 x)+1)^2}-\frac{2 \sin (2 x) \cos (x)}{\sin ^2(2 x)+(\cos (2 x)+1)^2}\right)$

and finally, `Simplify` both real and imaginary part:

```
Simplify[(2 Sin[x])/((1 + Cos[2 x])^2 + Sin[2 x]^2) + (2 Cos[2 x] Sin[x])/((1 + Cos[2 x])^2 + Sin[2 x]^2) - (2 Cos[x] Sin[2 x])/((1 + Cos[2 x])^2 + Sin[2 x]^2)]

(* 0 *)

Simplify[(2 Cos[x])/((1 + Cos[2 x])^2 + Sin[2 x]^2) + (2 Cos[x] Cos[2 x])/((1 + Cos[2 x])^2 + Sin[2 x]^2) + (2 Sin[x] Sin[2 x])/((1 + Cos[2 x])^2 + Sin[2 x]^2)]

(* Sec[x] *)
```